# Element Modulo P expressible as Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$. Can someone help me show that every $c\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is expressible in the form $x^2+ay^2$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? I'm not entirely sure where to start, but could examining the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-a}]$ modded out by $p$ be useful? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Define the sets $S_1=\{c-x^2:x\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\}$ and $S_2=\{ay^2:y\in \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\}$, count the number of elements in each set and deduce $S_1\cap S_2\neq\emptyset$.