# Nonempty Intersection of Sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Define $\mathfrak{A}=\{c-x^2:x\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}\}$ and $\mathfrak{B}=\{ay^2:y\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}\}$, where $a$ ranges over all elements in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}^{\times}$ and $c\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ and $p$ is prime. Can someone help me show that $\mathfrak{A}\cap\mathfrak{B}\neq\emptyset$? I have some ideas of using a pigeonhole approach, but I'm not sure how to formalize/proceed with this.

Comment: Oh sorry, i should have clarified: $a\in(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})^*$ and $c\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. I want to use this to show that every $c\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ can be expressed as $x^2+ay^2$ for $x,y,a$ defined as before.

Comment: Can't we just measure the sizes of $\mathfrak A,\mathfrak B$?

Comment: Yeah sorry $p$ is prime.

Comment: Given $\mathfrak{U}$ and $ \mathfrak{B}$ are $a, c$ fixed?

Comment: Essentially I need help proving this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530503/element-modulo-p-expressible-as-norm

Comment: If $p$ is odd, then there are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ squares in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$, including the $0$. So both, $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ contains $\frac{p+1}{2}$ elements. Pigeonhole: they intersect. For $p = 2$, we have two squares.

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you explain a bit more why they intersect b/c of Pigeonhole?

Comment: You have $p$ holes in $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. And you have $2\cdot \frac{p+1}{2} = p+1$ things to put in the holes. At least one hole must contain two things. But no hole can contain two things from $\mathfrak{A}$ or two things from $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: **I think you should acknowledge the topic from where your question comes from**: your question is, in fact, my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530503/element-modulo-p-expressible-as-norm/531151#531151) and maybe you are the same user with a different username.